# EF6 Foreign Key to an existing column in DB

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

i have a db schema, & im using EF6 code first migration.
i want to add foreign key from the dbo.aspnetuser to an existing column in my db (using MSSQL)
is it possible? how to do it ?

changing the file of migration to this, didn't work:
The Foreign Key on table 'dbo.AspNetUsers' with columns 'consumer_id' could not be created because the principal key columns could not be determined. Use the AddForeignKey fluent API to fully specify the Foreign Key.

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserName = c.String(),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    contact_firstname = c.String(),
                    contact_lastname = c.String(),
                    contact_phone = c.String(),
                    contact_phone2 = c.String(),
                    contact_email = c.String(),
                    country = c.String(),
                    state = c.String(),
                    city = c.String(),
                    street = c.String(),
                    postcode = c.String(),
                    longitude = c.Double(),
                    latitude = c.Double(),
                    consumer_id = c.Long(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.fx_service_consumers", t => t.consumer_id, cascadeDelete: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using fluent api for mapping object to table?

I use this to map foreign key for Address in Person object:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.PersonAddress ).WithRequiredDependent()
            .Map(m => m.MapKey("IdAddressColumnNameInUserTable"));
```

and my object

```
public class Person
{
     public int id {get;set;}
     public virtual Address PersonAddress {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int city {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, the only thing is that i don't have the other class in my schema, it's in the DB. I've managed to continue without foreginkey. thank's

Comment: @eyalewin can you please post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading and debating, it seems like there isn't a good way to use Foreign Key on table 'dbo.AspNetUsers', i've managed to continue without a Foreign Key and it works fine to me.